# How to change my HMS IAP product type from non-consumable to consumable?

Tags: in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services

I was setting up a few of my in-app purchases products; I accidentally saved one of the products with the wrong type - consumable. All of my products should be non-consumable. I poked around the interface but couldn't find any way to change the product type, I thought I can delete and recreate the same product ID with the correct type but it won't let me.

I thought about deleting the entire app but it will be so much work to redo everything again, I want to use the same product ID since I am using the same product IDs on other platforms.

Is there any other way to change this product to non-consumable?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official developer documentation, once you have created an IAP product ID and set the product type, you can no longer modify the type and use the same ID again. Unfortunately, your options are to recreate another app and create the product ID/type again; or I suggest that you use another product ID for this particular app.

[image]

Comment: I missed this part... so there is no other way at all? Like changing the product ID in the backend?

Comment: I am sorry that there is no way to modify the developer's backend IAP/product data.

Comment: Ok, I guess I will need to recreate an app. Thanks.